# Hive column delimiters different behaviour

Tags: hive, delimiter

I have a log file in format: date, time, log level, component, message. All fields delimited by space. For example:

21/06/13 14:42:58.874 FLW CPTView::CPTView Run as a service

I am creating table:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_messages_temp (date STRING,time STRING,severity STRING,component STRING,message STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\040' LOCATION '/examples/hive/tmp';`

When I am running query 
`SELECT message FROM log_messages_temp WHERE time = '14:42:58.874' LIMIT 50;
I receive single word "Run" instead of "Run as a service"`

How to define setting to Hive parser to take all remains string (without space parsing) and put it into last message column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you load the data first into single column temporary table.

For ex: You single column table will be as follows:-

say your temporary table is temp_table(dummy string)

i.e dummy will contain whole string i.e "21/06/13 14:42:58.874 FLW CPTView::CPTView Run as a service"

Now you can write a UDF that will parse each entries on the temp_table. Now parsing split the each record with space. Now I am assuming first four fields i.e date , time, severity , component  does not contain any space as your last field i.e message. Now take the first 4 spits and pass as it is. For the rest splits you can club them up using quotes say  in this fashion **Run_as_a_service**.

Use this UDF to finaly load into your final table.

I hope this will help your cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not load the data into single column table but associate Hive table with existing in HDFS files. But you are right I can associate it with single column table. Can you share some UDF java example?